# Swift - altering constant properties after delay

Tags: ios, swift

When i execute the below snippet, i end up with alert with the text 'mama' rather than the alert with the text 'hey' changing to 'mama' in 3 seconds.

I can't figure out why that is.

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "hey", message: "hey", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "cheese")
    alert.show()

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time_t(3000000000), dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        alert.message = "mama"
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE** As mentioned in the below answer and comments, the problem was with how i was using `dispatch_after()`.

This works also:

```
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(
        DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
        Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ), dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        alert.message = "mama"
    }
```

Comment: The first parameter to `dispatch_after` isn't a delay, it's a time. You can generate a time using [`dispatch_time`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/3/dispatch_time/).

Comment: @NateCook yes, you're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "hey", message: "hey", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "cheese")
        alert.show()
        delay(3) {
            alert.message = "mama"
        }
    }

    func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
```